# How to get count of words from DataFrame based on conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp, pandas-groupby

I have the following two dataframes `badges` and `comments`. I have created a list of 'gold users' from `badges` dataframe whose `Class=1`.

Here `Name` means the 'Name of Badge' and `Class` means the level of Badge (1=Gold, 2=Silver, 3=Bronze).

I have already done the text preprocessing on `comments['Text']`and now want to find the count of top 10 words for gold users from `comments['Text']`.

I tried the given code but am getting error
"KeyError: "None of [Index(['1532', '290', '1946', '1459', '6094', '766', '10446', '3106', '1',\n       '1587',\n       ...\n       '35760', '45979', '113061', '35306', '104330', '40739', '4181', '58888',\n       '2833', '58158'],\n      dtype='object', length=1708)] are in the [index]". Please provide me a way to fix this.

**Note**
I had some answers from datascience.stackexchange but they did not work. [Link to StackExchange Problem](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/77080/keyerror-selecting-text-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-of-another-dataframe)

**Dataframe 1 (badges)**

```
   Id | UserId |  Name          |        Date              |Class | TagBased
   2  | 23     | Autobiographer | 2016-01-12T18:44:49.267  |   3  | False
   3  | 22     | Autobiographer | 2016-01-12T18:44:49.267  |   3  | False
   4  | 21     | Autobiographer | 2016-01-12T18:44:49.267  |   3  | False
   5  | 20     | Autobiographer | 2016-01-12T18:44:49.267  |   3  | False
   6  | 19     | Autobiographer | 2016-01-12T18:44:49.267  |   3  | False
```

**Dataframe 2 (comments)**

```
   Id|                    Text                             |    UserId  
    6|  [2006, course, allen, knutsons, 2001, course, ...  |    3   
    8|  [also, theo, johnsonfreyd, note, mark, haimans...  |    1
```

**Code**

```
#Classifying Users
df_gold_users = badges[(badges['Class'] == '1')]
df_silver_users = badges[(badges['Class'] != '1') & (badges['Class'] == '2') ]
df_bronze_users = badges[(badges['Class'] != '1') & (badges['Class'] != '2') & (badges['Class'] == '3')]

gold_users = df_gold_users['UserId'].value_counts().index
silver_users = df_silver_users['UserId'].value_counts().index
bronze_users = df_bronze_users['UserId'].value_counts().index

#Text Cleaning (clean_text function tokenizes and lemmatizes)
comments['Text'] = comments['Text'].apply(lambda x: clean_text(x))

#Getting comments made by Gold Users
for index,rows in comments.iterrows():
  gold_comments = rows[comments.Text.loc[gold_users]]
  Counter(gold_comments)
```

**Expected Output**

```
#Top 10 Words that appear the most in the comments made by gold users with their count.
 [['scholar',20],['school',18],['bus',15],['class',14],['teacher',14],['bell',13],['time',12],['books',11],['bag',9],'student',7]]
```

Comment: Maybe you could post a more complete code example, for example the structure of `gold_users` would be important. Can you try replacing `gold_users` by `comments.UserId.isin(gold_users)`? Assuming that you want to look up by `UserId` and not by the data frame index...

Comment: `badges[badges['id'].isin(comments['id'].tolist())]` ? unsure what you need / want please post your expected output

Comment: @DavidWierichs I have added the complete code, please have a look.

Comment: @Datanovice I have added the expected output. In simple words I have picked up users from `badges` dataframe for whom `class=1` i.e., gold. Now I want to segregate the `comments['Text']` rows for those gold users so that I can ultimately find out the top 10 words used by gold users.

Comment: @DavidWierichs I tried you method and it is giving the error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import itertools

df_gold_users = badges[(badges['Class'] == '1')]
df=pd.merge(df_gold_users,comments,on='UserId')
gold_text=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df['Text'].to_list()))
gold_text=list(map(lambda x:[x,1],gold_text))
gold_text_df=pd.DataFrame(gold_text,columns=['Text','xyz'])
gold_text_df=gold_text_df.groupby('Text')['xyz'].count().reset_index().sort_values(by=['xyz'], ascending=False)
gold_text_df(10).values.tolist()
```

Comment: I ran all code statements individually, it is the for loop that is just loading, rest statements are executed.

Comment: I made some changes in my answer, please check once and let me know.