# Word Counter loop keeps loading forever in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, nlp

I have a DataFrame `comments` as seen below. I want to make a `Counter` of words for the `Text` field. I have made a list of `UserId` whose count of words is needed, those `UserId`s are stored in `gold_users`. But the loop to create `Counter` just keeps loading. Please help me fix this.

**comments**
*This is just part of dataframe, original has many rows.*

```
Id|                    Text                             |    UserId  
 6|  Before the 2006 course, there was Allen Knutso...  |    3   
 8|  Also, Theo Johnson-Freyd has some notes from M...  |    1
```

**Code**

```
#Text Cleaning

punct = set(string.punctuation)
stopword = set(stopwords.words('english'))
lm = WordNetLemmatizer()

def clean_text(text):
    text = ''.join(char.lower() for char in text if char not in punct)
    tokens = re.split('\W+', text)
    text = [lm.lemmatize(word) for word in tokens if word not in stopword]
    return tuple(text)         # Writing only `return text` was giving unhashable error 'list'

comments['Text'] = comments['Text'].apply(lambda x: clean_text(x))

    
for index,rows in comments.iterrows():
      gold_comments = rows[comments.Text.loc[comments.UserId.isin(gold_users)]]
      Counter(gold_comments)
```

**Expected Output**

```
[['scholar',20],['school',18],['bus',15],['class',14],['teacher',14],['bell',13],['time',12],['books',11],['bag',9],'student',7],......]
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing your dataframe already having only your `gold_users` ids and texts, the following pure python function returns exactly what you need:

```
def word_count(df):
    counts = dict()
    for str in df['Text']:
        words = str.split()
        for word in words:
            if word in counts:
                counts[word] += 1
            else:
                counts[word] = 1
    return list(counts.items())
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You overcomplicated the problem, I am afraid. In Pandas, it is almost never desirable to iterate through the rows. Select the rows that meet your condition, add their Texts, and apply a Counter to the combined list:

```
gold_users = [3,1]
golden_comments = comments[comments['UserId'].isin(gold_users)]
counter = Counter(golden_comments['Text'].sum())
```

If necessary, convert the counter to a list of lists:

```
[[k, v] for k, v in counter.items()]
# [['2006', 1], ['course', 1], ['allen', 1], ...]
```

Comment: The comments dataframe has many rows I have shown only a part of it.

Comment: I tried it, but its the same. The code cell just keeps loading and does not give any output. Please have a look at this link, it has a more detailed description of the code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62728898/how-to-get-count-of-words-from-dataframe-based-on-conditions

Comment: About 600K rows are there.

Comment: That may be the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
# Initialise packages in session: 
import pandas as pd
import re

# comments => Data Frame
comments = pd.DataFrame({"Id": [6, 8], 
            "Text": ["Before the 2006 course, there was Allen Knutso...", 
                     "Also, Theo Johnson-Freyd has some notes from M..."],
            "UserId": [3, 1]})

# Stopwords to remove from text: stopwords_lst => list of strings 
stopwords_lst = ['i', 'me', 'my', 'myself', 'we', 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'you', "you're", "you've", 
                 "you'll", "you'd", 'your', 'yours', 'yourself', 'yourselves', 'he', 'him', 'his', 'himself', 
                 'she', "she's", 'her', 'hers', 'herself', 'it', "it's", 'its', 'itself', 'they', 'them', 'their', 
                 'theirs', 'themselves', 'what', 'which', 'who', 'whom', 'this', 'that', "that'll", 'these', 
                 'those', 'am', 'is', 'are', 'was', 'were', 'be', 'been', 'being', 'have', 'has', 'had', 'having', 
                 'do', 'does', 'did', 'doing', 'a', 'an', 'the', 'and', 'but', 'if', 'or', 'because', 'as', 
                 'until', 'while', 'of', 'at', 'by', 'for', 'with', 'about', 'against', 'between', 'into', 
                 'through', 'during', 'before', 'after', 'above', 'below', 'to', 'from', 'up', 'down', 'in', 
                 'out', 'on', 'off', 'over', 'under', 'again', 'further', 'then', 'once', 'here', 'there', 'when', 
                 'where', 'why', 'how', 'all', 'any', 'both', 'each', 'few', 'more', 'most', 'other', 'some', 
                 'such', 'no', 'nor', 'not', 'only', 'own', 'same', 'so', 'than', 'too', 'very', 's', 't', 'can', 
                 'will', 'just', 'don', "don't", 'should', "should've", 'now', 'd', 'll', 'm', 'o', 're', 've', 
                 'y', 'ain', 'aren', "aren't", 'couldn', "couldn't", 'didn', "didn't", 'doesn', "doesn't", 'hadn', 
                 "hadn't", 'hasn', "hasn't", 'haven', "haven't", 'isn', "isn't", 'ma', 'mightn', "mightn't", 
                 'mustn', "mustn't", 'needn', "needn't", 'shan', "shan't", 'shouldn', "shouldn't", 'wasn', 
                 "wasn't", 'weren', "weren't", 'won', "won't", 'wouldn', "wouldn't"]

# Clean lists of strings using regex: list of strings => function() => list of strings
def clean_string_list(str_lst):
    """Convert all alpha numeric characters in list of strings to lowercase, 
    non alpha-numeric characters to whitepsace, and trim whitespace on both sides of each string. 
    
    Args:
        str_lst (list): Function takes a list of strings. 
    
    Returns:
        (list) A list of strings        
    """
    return([*map(lambda x: re.sub('\W+', ' ', x.lower().strip('\s+\t\n\r')), str_lst)])

# Store a list of gold user's UserIds: gold_user_ids => list of integers: 
gold_user_ids = [3, 1]

# Take Subset of Data Frame containing only gold users: gold_users => Data Frame
gold_users = comments[comments["UserId"].isin(gold_user_ids)]

# Apply the function to the list of stopwords and collapse the list into a single string: stopwords_re => string
stopwords_re =  ' | '.join(clean_string_list(stopwords_lst))

# Clean strings, and remove stopwords: cleaned_text => vector of strings
gold_users['cleaned_text'] = [*map(lambda y: re.sub(stopwords_re, ' ', y), clean_string_list(gold_users['Text']))]

# Split each word on whitespace: words => list of strings
words = (' '.join(gold_users['cleaned_text'])).split()

# Count the number of occurences of each word: word_count => dict
word_count = dict(zip(words, [*map(lambda z: words.count(z), words)]))

# Print words to console: dictionary => stdout
print(word_count)
```

Comment: The comments dataframe has many rows I have shown only a part of it.

Comment: I understand that, I have created a reproducible example in my code in order for myself and others to create the Data Frame object. You (OP) do not have to recreate your Data Frame as I have done in my code.

Comment: Moreover, my code should work regardless of the number of observations contained in your Data Frame.